# How to erase an vector element in this situation?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I made a game, rambo shoots bullets and bullets hit zombies and I want to erase the zombie who got hit, from the zombie vector.

This nested loop checks collision between every zombie and bullet one by one. It works good for a while but when I start killing more, at some point, it crashes because it wants to use a function of erased zombie.

```
for ( it = zombies.begin(); it != zombies.end(); ++it ) {
    it->attack();
    for (rambo.it = rambo.bullets.begin(); rambo.it != rambo.bullets.end(); ++rambo.it) {
        if(checkBasicCollision(it,rambo.it) && it != zombies.end()){
            zombies.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```

I've added `it--;` after `zombies.erase(it);` works better now but it still crashes sometimes.

I think its happening like, for example there are 5 zombies and 20 bullets, zombie iterator is at second zombie, and second zombie starts the bullet loop to check if it got hit. Loop starts, lets say third bullet hit the zombie, but loop is still going, even if zombie is erased, it still continues the loop.

I've added break; after `zombies.erase(it);` now it hasn't got any problem. But the code looks so dirty. Is there another way to erase the current element easily

Comment: Anytime you end up writing code that erases from a sequence container while iterating over the same sequence container, it's time to rethink what you're trying to accomplish.  You should strive to not write code that erases from the same container you're iterating over.  Instead, use the `remove(if)/erase` idiom as best as possible.  Not only will you have less issues (usually no issues) of having invalidated iterators, you have refactored your code into "logically" what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why don't you store zombies in a list instead?

Comment: What is the interest of `rambo.it` by the way ? It seems like this should be a temporary variable.

Answer (score 5):

While the solution for manually erasing was presented, note that it is not the most idiomatic one. In idiomatic C++ you would make use of the `std::remove_if` algorithm in the erase-remove idiom like so:

```
// 1. A predicate that check whether a zombie was it by any bullet:
auto is_zombie_hit = [&rambo](Zombie const& zombie) {
    auto is_bullet_hitting_zombie = [&zombie](Bullet const& bullet) {
        return checkBasicCollision(zombie, bullet);
    };

    return std::any_of(
        rambo.bullets.begin(),
        rambo.bullets.end(),
        is_bullet_hitting_zombie
    );
};

// 2. Use the erase-remove idiom:
zombies.erase(
    std::remove_if(zombies.begin(), zombies.end(), is_zombie_hit),
    zombies.end()
);
```

*Note: yes, you can use lambda in-place, however I prefer naming them to indicate their role.*

*Note: this uses C++11, however replacing lambda with predicates is trivial and an implementation of `any_of` is easy enough to produce, much like `all_of` and `none_of`.*

Comment: This IMO is the superior solution, especially if the container is a sequence container such as `vector`.  I get a code smell anytime I see erasure code in a loop that iterates over the container.

Answer (score 4):

To use `erase` you need to use the returned value and assign it back to the iterator so it is valid for the next iteration.

```
for ( it = zombies.begin(); it != zombies.end(); ) {
    it->attack();
    for (rambo.it = rambo.bullets.begin(); rambo.it != rambo.bullets.end(); ++rambo.it) {
        if(checkBasicCollision(it,rambo.it) && it != zombies.end()){
            it = zombies.erase(it);    // erase will increment the iterator
        }
        else{
            ++it;    // no erase, increment the iterator manually
        }
    }
}
```

From the documetion for [`vector::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) the return value is:

> An iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element erased by the function call. This is the container end if the operation erased the last element in the sequence.

Comment: That won't work.  it = zombies.erase(it) will move the iterator to the next item.  And ++it will move the iterator again.  So this will skip the item after the one that got deleted.

Comment: I've tried that already, it does not work as Trade-Ideas Philip said.

Comment: Please see the latest update for how to handle that situation. Note that you no longer have the increment in the `for` statement, it is taken care of within the `if-else` block.

Comment: If one of the bullets is not colliding, it will drop to else block and it won't check other bullets because the zombie changes with ++it;

Comment: If the last zombie collides with the first bullet, this code will exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: Still flawed.  Consider the case where the second bullet hits the second zombie and the first bullet should hit the third zombie.  You will correctly delete the second zombie.  Then you will immediately make the iterator point to the third zombie without restarting the inner loop.  So you will never compare the third zombie to the first bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
auto zombie_tail = std::remove_if(zombies.begin(), zombies.end(), [&](Zombie const & zombie) {
        zombie.attack();
        return std::any_of(rambo.bullets.begin(), rambo.bullets.end(), [&](Bullet const & bullet) {
            return checkBasicCollision(zombie, bullet);
        });
    });

zombies.erase(zombie_tail, zombies.end());
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to stay away from c++ algorithms:

```
for (it = zombies.begin(); it != zombies.end(); ) {
    it->attack();

    // Attempt to find a bullet that hit.
    for(rambo.it = rambo.bullets.begin(); rambo.it != rambo.bullets.end(); ++rambo.it)
        if (checkBasicCollision(it, rambo.it))
            break;

    // Possibly remove the zombie, and advance the iterator
    if (rambo.it != rambo.bullets.end())
        it = zombies.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When erasing vector elements, iterators and indices become invalidated. Also your code is incorrect for the case 2 or more bullets hit the same zombie (if it is possible). Because with the second bullet the inner loop will try to erase the zombie that was already hit. Instead, you should do it like this:

```
for ( uint i = 0; i < zombies.size(); ++i)
{
    for( auto it = rambo.bullets.begin(); it != rambo.bullets.end(); ++it)
    {
         if(checkBasicCollision(zombies[i], it)
         {
             zombies.erase( zombies.begin() + i );
             --i;
             break; // zombie is dead (well, technically it was already dead)
             // so no further checks are needed (i.e. exit inner loop)
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

direct, easy to read and grasp, but maybe not very fancy;

```
for ( auto& z : zombies )
    z.attack();

for( auto& b : rambo.bullets )
{
    auto itr = zombies.begin();
    while( itr != zombies.end() )
    {
        if( checkBasicCollision(b,*itr) )
            itr = zombies.erase(itr);
        else
            ++itr;
    }
}
```

`checkBasicCollision` now takes references, not iterators